# Reading Active Directory on Windows XP Machine

Tags: c#, .net, activedirectorymembership

i have the Problem that i cant connect (and read) the active directory under windows xp. 
The solutions ive tryed so far are

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/StorerActiveDirectory.aspx

and

http://linqtoad.codeplex.com

I need to read the groups of the current user.

Thanks a lot!

Regards
Denis

Comment: What error are you getting when you try to connect to AD? And what server version (Windows 2008, Windows 2003, etc.) is hosting the domain?

Comment: The Server is a Windows Server 2008 R2

I get the Exception...

System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x8007203A): The server is not
operational

  at System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.Bind(Boolean throwIfFail)

  at System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.Bind()

  at System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.get_AdsObject()

  at System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher.FindAll(Boolean
findMoreThanOne)

  at System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher.FindOne()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pointing the DNS of TCP/IP v4 to the Active Directory Server solves the problem.